# jHipster Application fails to run after upgrade to 5.8.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jhipster

I have a jhipster Application (monolith) and made an upgrade from 5.4.2 to 5.8.2.

I resolved all conflicts and compilations issues.

I'm able to run the application with the "dev" profile active. All tests pass and the application works as expected.

However, as soon as I build the application for "prod" an run it with the "prod" profile, I get an exception that I can't find the reason for:

```
2019-03-01 17:11:04.437  WARN 24308 --- [           main]
ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : 

Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name
 'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ProxyAsyncConfiguration':

Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:

Error creating bean with name 'asyncConfiguration' defined in URL 

[jar:file:/***/config/AsyncConfiguration.class]: 

Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;

nested exception is 
org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: 

Error creating bean with name 'io.github.jhipster.config.JHipsterProperties': 

Could not bind properties to 'JHipsterProperties' : 
prefix=jhipster, 
ignoreInvalidFields=false, 
ignoreUnknownFields=false; 

nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: 
Failed to bind properties under 'jhipster' to 
io.github.jhipster.config.JHipsterProperties
```

I tried to check similar issues, but couldn't find a link to my application setup and how to fix it:

https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry/issues/279

https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/8195

I hope that someone can provide me with some hints on how to resolve the issue.

Many thanks for any help,
regards.

Comment: Looks like an issue with your application-prod.yml

Answer (score 0):

Ok ... I don't know exactly what I changed. At least I cannot find anything in my git-history that would explain the "fix". After several rebuilds and tests I couldn't reproduce the issue.

Probably I made an error during build of the application?

Anyway - things I obvserved:

I compared the application-prod.yml generated on a blank project with my project. There where some differences, but these where DB, SSL and Mail stuff that are expected.

3 Things I found (and I can't believe these to be problems):
- logging file name was removed from application.yml in 5.8.2 (?). I added it to application-prod.yml
- metrix -> jmx was removed in application-prod.yml in 5.8.2 -> I removed it from mine as well
- I added useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC to the datasource url as this was new as well in 5.8.2